# Serialize c# class to xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse to xml a class, however I am not getting the result that I want.
Let me explain:

Those are the classes the:

```
public class ParCard
{
    public string ExtrFreq { get; set; }
    public string LastDay { get; set; }
    public string FolderPath { get; set; }
    public List<EFile> Files { get; set; }
    //public List<string> Files { get; set; }
    public string FTPAddress { get; set; }
    public string FTPPath { get; set; }
    public string FTPUser { get; set; }
    public string FTPPass { get; set; }
}

public class EFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the actual result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ParCard xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ExtrFreq>Daily</ExtrFreq>
<LastDay>20140101</LastDay>
<FolderPath>c:\Temp\</FolderPath>
<Files>
  <EFile>
    <FileName>file1.txt</FileName>
  </EFile>
  <EFile>
    <FileName>file2.txt</FileName>
  </EFile>
  <EFile>
    <FileName>file3.txt</FileName>
  </EFile>
</Files>
<FTPAddress>10.1.1.100</FTPAddress>
<FTPPath>Home</FTPPath>
<FTPUser>User</FTPUser>
<FTPPass>Pass</FTPPass>
</ParCard>
```

and this is what I want to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ParCard xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ExtrFreq>Daily</ExtrFreq>
<LastDay>20140101</LastDay>
<FolderPath>c:\Temp\</FolderPath>
<Files>
  <FileName>file1.txt</FileName>
  <FileName>file2.txt</FileName>
  <FileName>file3.txt</FileName>
</Files>
<FTPAddress>10.1.1.100</FTPAddress>
<FTPPath>Home</FTPPath>
<FTPUser>User</FTPUser>
<FTPPass>Pass</FTPPass>
```

For serialize I using:

```
static public void Serialize(ParCard pc)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ParCard));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Teste.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, pc);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?!?!? Can you point me out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your desired output, you need to change your `List` to a list of strings:

```
public List<EFile> Files { get; set; }
```

becomes

```
public List<string> Files { get; set; }
```

You are getting the extra XML nodes because the File property is inside another class.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a better way, but this works:

```
public class ParCard
{
    public string ExtrFreq { get; set; }
    public string LastDay { get; set; }
    public string FolderPath { get; set; }
    public EFile Files { get; set; }
    public string FTPAddress { get; set; }
    public string FTPPath { get; set; }
    public string FTPUser { get; set; }
    public string FTPPass { get; set; }
}

public class EFile
{
    [XmlElement("FileName")]
    public List<string> FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your not willing to give up the initial structure, and follow @Pheonixblade9's answer, then you could always do a hack to get it as you want, while still using the EFile class. The ShouldSerialize{} method returning bool tells the serializer on how to treat the corresponding property, which in this case we want to do some other stuff aswell, like copy the contents of Files into a new List in FilesAsString. Then well ignore the original Files property, with XmlIgnore, and then redefine the names on the collection as well as elements with XmlArray and XmlArrayItem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ParCard pc = new ParCard();
        pc.ExtrFreq = "Daily";
        pc.LastDay = "20140101";
        pc.FolderPath = @"c:\temp";
        pc.Files = new List<EFile>() { new EFile() { FileName = "file1.txt" }, new EFile { FileName = "file2.txt" } };
        pc.FTPAddress = "10.1.1.100";
        pc.FTPPath = "Home";
        pc.FTPUser = "User";
        pc.FTPPass = "Pass";

        Serialize(pc);
    }

    static public void Serialize(ParCard pc)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ParCard));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"Teste.xml"))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, pc);
        }
    }
}

public class ParCard
{
    public string ExtrFreq { get; set; }
    public string LastDay { get; set; }
    public string FolderPath { get; set; } 

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<EFile> Files { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Files"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(string), ElementName = "FileName")]
    public List<string> FilesAsString { get; set; }
    public string FTPAddress { get; set; }
    public string FTPPath { get; set; }
    public string FTPUser { get; set; }
    public string FTPPass { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeFilesAsString()
    {
        List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var eFile in Files)
        {
            fileNames.Add(eFile.FileName);
        }

        FilesAsString = fileNames;
        return true;
    }
}


public class EFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

This will produce the output you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ParCard xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ExtrFreq>Daily</ExtrFreq>
    <LastDay>20140101</LastDay>
    <FolderPath>c:\temp</FolderPath>
    <Files>
        <FileName>file1.txt</FileName>
        <FileName>file2.txt</FileName>
    </Files>
    <FTPAddress>10.1.1.100</FTPAddress>
    <FTPPath>Home</FTPPath>
    <FTPUser>User</FTPUser>
    <FTPPass>Pass</FTPPass>
</ParCard>
```